# I cannot use a variable in `fastcgi_pass` directive

Tags: nginx

I cannot use a variable for `fastcgi_pass` directive as below

```
fastcgi_pass $image:9000;
```

I get the following error.

```
 2020/07/07 01:39:08 [error] 27#27: *1 no resolver defined to resolve php, client: 192.168.48.1, server: , request: "GET /info.temp.php HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.3"
```

The `$image` variable has a valid value and if I hard code the value instead of the variable it will start to work.

Any workaround or fix please?

Comment: Is this happens inside a docker container?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes. it does

Comment: You probably need to use `resolver 127.0.0.11;` inside the docker, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466891/nginx-in-docker-proxy-path-to-subdomain/58471241#58471241) answer.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Many Thanks. It fixed it. You are the best!

Comment: @IvanShatsky It's so strange that a variable behaves differently than  it's the same value

Comment: Nothing strange to me with that, when you are using fixed value for a host field, nginx can resolve its address on startup, but when you are using a variable, nginx doesn't know its value on startup and needs to use some DNS server to resolve it. nginx implements its own non-blocking DNS resolving since the default system name resolution is a blocking one, so you need to specify the name server that will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_pass) states:

> Parameter value can contain variables. In this case, if an address is specified as a domain name, the name is searched among the described server groups, and, if not found, is determined using a resolver.

You need to have a [resolver](https://nginx.org/r/resolver) configured because the value didn't match any of your defined [upstream](https://nginx.org/r/upstream) servers.